# What does "beacon of European sophistication" mean in this context?

Tags: meaning, expressions, meaning-in-context, translation

Please help me to find the meaning of this context:

> Argentina, which for many years portrayed itself as a **beacon of European sophistication** in a continent of New World backwardness,now is a poor country.

Comment: Please include the research you’ve done, or consider if your question suits our [ELL.se] site better. Questions that can be answered using commonly-available references are off-topic. A good place to start would be to look up any words you're unfamiliar with in a dictionary or translating dictionary.

Comment: @DanBron Native speakers, esp. monolingual ones, often underestimate the difficulty a non-native speaker faces when trying to  find the "correct" meaning of a word in a dictionary. I myself had to look hard to find a reference that associates *sophistication* with *progress*. Keep in mind that the primary purpose of this site is to help people, not discipline them.

Comment: @michael.hor257k I don’t disagree with anything you say. Except the implication is that this site is designed to help non-naive speakers. That isn’t the case. This site is aimed at native and fluent speakers, and in particular with a focus on theory, not practice. We have a different site aimed at helping non-native speakers learn the language, with a bent towards practical problems and pedagogy: [ELL.se], linked from my first comment. This question should be asked and answered there.

Comment: @DanBron I don't think this site is aimed at native speakers only. Fluent (reasonably fluent, at least), yes - but not necessarily native. I often vote to close questions as belonging to ELL, but I am not at all convinced this is a good candidate.

Comment: @michael.hor257k I did say native and fluent. And I think this post, while nicely formatted, demonstrates an insufficient command of the language to pass the bar. I could also make an argument on the basis of “no research”, like saying running this through Google Translate first, but I don’t think that’s the most material element here. Questions for this site should pass the bar “not immediately answerable by a native speaker with no additional training”, or at the least be *interesting* to that audience. They should at least have some potential to bear on theory.

Comment: I also feel obliged to point out that posting on ELL is not a punishment or insult. It’s designed to help people who want become fluent in the language, become fluent in the language. Too many people model it mentally as “the kids’ table” or something. Not at all, it’s simply for a different audience.

Comment: @DanBron Well, then I guess we disagree on the meaning of *and*, among other things.

Comment: Now the ambiguity of *and*, if any, is a topic worthy of ELU!

Answer (score 1):

The word ***beacon*** here is used figuratively to mean:

> 7. a person or thing that serves as a guide, inspiration, or warning
>      [Collins English Dictionary](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/beacon)

The word ***sophistication*** is contrasted with ***backwardness*** - so in this context it means ***advance***:

> ***[sophisticated](http://www.yourdictionary.com/sophisticated)***
>     The definition of sophisticated is someone that is intelligently worldly and smart or advanced processes or technology.

---

In other words, ***a beacon of European sophistication*** could be rephrased as ***a leader in European progress***.

Comment: So, this answer is not useful? Or perhaps there *are* [malicious downvoters](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10241/194459)?

Comment: *A beacon of sophistication* reminds me strongly of *a paragon of virtue*.

Comment: @JasonBassford Yes: I think the original sentence is a bit sarcastic (note the "portrayed itself").